# Conceptual problems - Trim "silence" at beginning/end of wav

Tags: matlab

I need to compute the length of a wav file by trimming off the "relative" silence at the beginning and end of the file then return the duration in milliseconds. I know you can find the duration of a wav file as such:

```
[w,fs] = wavread('file.wav');
length = length(w)/fs;
```

My logic is to use the first column of the waveform matrix (left channel), get an arbitrary threshold value, then traverse the matrix through sample windows. If the maximum value of these windows is greater than the threshold then I start counting time there. When the max of this window is less than the value I stop there. This is what I have so far:

```
%Just use the first column in the waveform matrix, 2 gives strange results
w = w(:,1);
%Get threshold value by multiplying max amplitude of waveform and
%predetermined percentage (this varies with testing)
thold = max(w) * .04;
```

Just need help on how to actually traverse the matrix through sampling windows.

Comment: So I could do something like: `silenceInd = find(abs(w) < thold)`? Wouldn't that find values less than the threshold everywhere in the matrix?

Comment: Well, you have to identify several samples of consecutive silence (say, 1/2 second of silence) to declare an actual silence.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely certain what you want to achieve, but I think you can use your own suggestion (sort of):

```
soundIdx                      = find(abs(w) > thold)
total_time_w_sound            = sum(abs(w) > thold)/fs;
time_from_first_sound_to_last = (soundIdx(end)-soundIdx(1))/fs;
```

Is it one of those you are trying to find?